# Floating Action Button wrong position in TableLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-support-library, android-tablelayout, floating-action-button

As you can see `TableLayout` changes width of `Button` , `ProgressBar` and `EditText` components, but does not do the same for my `FloatingActionButton`.

1. Here is a photo that explains my [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTOpw.png)
2. The result i want to [get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omOTZ.png)

In xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  >

   <TableLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"

       android:stretchColumns="*" >

       <TableRow
           android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

           <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
               android:id="@+id/FloatingActionButton04"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"

               android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
               app:elevation="4dp"
               app1:fabSize="mini" />

           <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
               android:id="@+id/FloatingActionButton03"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
               app:elevation="4dp" />

           <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
               android:id="@+id/FloatingActionButton02"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
               app:elevation="4dp" />

           <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
               android:id="@+id/FloatingActionButton01"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
               app:elevation="4dp" />

           <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
               android:id="@+id/myFAB"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
               app:elevation="4dp" />

       </TableRow>

       <TableRow
           android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/Button04"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Button" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/Button03"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Button" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/Button02"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Button" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/Button01"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Button" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/button1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Button" />

       </TableRow>

       <TableRow
           android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

           <ProgressBar
               android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
               style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:progress="60" />

       </TableRow>

       <TableRow
           android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/editText1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:ems="10"
               android:text="Width OK" >

               <requestFocus />
           </EditText>

       </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About Floating Action Button

A floating action button is used for a promoted action. Only one floating action button is recommended per screen to represent the most common action. Hence don't use so many action buttons in one raw. Use normal buttons instead